# Calendar events deleted on android phone but not deleted in web Google agenda

Tags: android, calendar, delete-row, android-calendar, agenda

My app download a planning and create new events in calendar (between 30 to 70). For each day, I first delete all the events of the day, then I create all new events. This is running fast : less than 5 seconds.

On my android phone, in the Google Agenda app, all the old events are correctly deleted, and all the new events are correctly added.

On the web Google Agenda (opened in Chrome), all the new events are correctly sync and added (after few seconds), but all the deleted events on phone are still there, and I have all events (if there is no change in planning) duplicated... If I try 10 times, events are duplicated 10 times (not on the phone).

How to be sure that synchronization has been successful ?

Is it a bug from Google ?

Is there a limitation for sync deletion ? (in my case more than 30 events deleted in less than 5 seconds)

Is it too much or too fast ? (I tried to add a thread.sleep(2000) between each day deletion but still the same...

Someone has a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after testing lot of solutions, I found why events are not deleted on computer.

It comes from my phone **Huawei P20**.

I tried on my Samsung tablet and now events are well deleted on computer !

Now I have to find why on Huawei P20 the events are kept on computer.if someone has a solution (some parameter to change ?) Thanks in advance !

**PS** : may be the problem is due to Android 9 ? other devices tested are all lower than android 8...

PS 2 : I changed my phone for a Xiaomi Mi9 and it's working fine under Android 9...

Answer (score 0):

If you delete cache from calendar app it works once! I have tried different apps for calendar. I guess that some of them use the same cache as built-in app. Now I use Calendar One, but there are probably . It is not affected with that "bug".